# Как определить тип дженерик аргумента в java?

Tags: java, generics

```
class ad<N>{
}
```

Можно ли собственно получить тип `N` наподобие `.getClass().getSimpleName()`?

Comment: В общем случае нет, потому что из-за type erasure для рантайма это идентично `class ad<Object>`. В некоторых случаях (при указании конкретного типа, например, `new ad<String>()`) подобная информация будет сохранена и ее можно будет извлечь, но в общем случае, опять же, это невозможно.

Comment: [`[java] [generics] тип is:q`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bgenerics%5D+тип+is%3Aq)

Answer (score 1):

Смотри на [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection<br).
Короче через reflections:

```
  Class<T> persistentClass = (Class<T>)
   ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
      .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```