# Положить конкретную переменную в generic тип

Tags: java, generics, типы

Происходит считывание с текстовика классов Node1(2/3), наследников абстрактного Node с полем `T object` представляющих Root/Parent/Child дерева. По условию задачи типов может быть только 3:

> В качестве значения object могут выступать: cтрока, 32-битное знаковое целочисленное число, 64-битное число с плавающей точкой.

Пока вижу одно решение, но как мне кажется не очень красивое:
   [прям-как-тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779410/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java) через getGenericSuperclass

- Вторая мысль это передавать Node1/2/3 через параметры метода и выполнять `Node1.object = int; (=string/=double)`, однако делать прям как в этой строке, очевидно, нельзя. Ругается что `Required: T / Found: int`

Собственно, вопрос. Как мне считать с файла нужный тип и задать Node1/2/3 поле `T object`?

Скорее всего что-то не замечаю, или не хватает опыта работы с generics

```
public static <T> T getValueFromString(String input)    
{
    String value = input.substring(input.indexOf("(") + 1, input.indexOf(")")); // остальная часть input дает понять Node1 Node2 или Node3 сейчас считывается

    int valueInt;
    double valueDouble;
    String valueString;

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input)) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) // если строка - int число
            return scanner.nextInt();
        else
            if (scanner.hasNextDouble())  // если строка - double число
                return scanner.nextDouble();
            else
                return value; // если строка - текст
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в понимании generic-ов. Generic - это не любой тип, какой ты туда пошлешь. В рантайме все типы generic-a уже должны быть известны. 
Я бы, на твоем месте заюзал factory, которая в зависимости от типа создавала бы правильный объект и сетила в него значение

Comment: Разве Вы сейчас не описали альтернативу блоку `try`?  Ведь если я буду создавать правильный объект типа int/double/string, мне все равно его нужно поместить в тип `T`.

То есть это сработает красиво если поменять `T` на `Object` в абстрактном, но тогда и код из вопроса по идее должен сработать

Comment: @ОльгаОмельчишина нет. Типа `Т` в рантайме нет. Вы пишите что-то вроде `MyType<String> obj = new MyType<>()`. Всё. Для этого объекта этот тип будет `String`. Всегда. Положить в этот же объект на то же место `int` не получится... Поменять на `Object` - плохой вариант (так делали, когда не было Generic-ов)... Покажите пожалуйста подробнее ваш код. Мне кажется, что беда в архитектуре

Comment: [тут](https://github.com/axsesolga/HW2) вы можете глянуть код. Но по сути все что написано кроме содержимого TreeImporter и методов ToStringForm - уже было в задании и никак не менялось

Comment: @ОльгаОмельчишина ага. Здесь идет сугубо import... Тогда, как я и сказал, отправляете строку в factory, которая должна вергуть экземпляр класса

Comment: Хм, Вы правы, стоило с нуля еще раз продумать реализацию, с Factory выходит отлично. Спасибо!

Comment: @ОльгаОмельчишина. Всегда пожалуйста.